# How AWS reservations work with different EC2 generation types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 26 **m4.2xlarge** EC2 instances and I want to make a year reservation to save £££. But "soon", probably after summer, I will recreate 20 of them so I would use **m5.2xlarge**.

Not sure how AWS reservations work with different EC2 generation types. I think (not sure) I've read in the past that either:

- If I reserve m4.2xlarge they will cover if I change them to m5.
- OR, if I reserve m5.2xlarge they will cover my m4's until I change them to m5.
- OR, none of above.

**How AWS reservations work with different EC2 generation types?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the instance family (m4 to m5 or c4) then you’ll need convertible reserved instances. If you want to change type within the family (m4.2xlarge to m4.large) you can with standard reserved instances.

See [here for how to exchange convertible reserved instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-convertible-exchange.html)

The answer to your specific question is none of the above.